# Color-Only Coloring Differs From Text+Color-Coloring

Tags: c, shell, graphics, terminal, ncurses

If I print a character using a `chtype`, the ncurses container object for characters, only specifying a color like `COLOR_PAIR(SOME_PAIR)`, I get two characters of color. Using `' ' | COLOR_PAIR(SOME_PAIR)`, that is, OR-ing with a character, I get just one, as I expected.

Try it yourself (build with `-lncurses`):

```
#include <ncurses.h>

#define RED 1

int main(void)
{
        initscr();
        start_color();
        curs_set(0);
        init_pair(RED, COLOR_RED, COLOR_RED);

        printw("Multiple: ");
        addch(COLOR_PAIR(RED));

        printw("\t\tSingle: ");
        addch(' ' | COLOR_PAIR(RED));

        getch();
        endwin();
}
```

It looks like this for me:
[image: Output of Program]

What's happening there? How can `addch` *ever* manipulate more than one character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `chtype` contains character and attribute data. Setting a `chtype` to `COLOR_PAIR(COLOR_RED)`, you set the attribute data, not the character data, effectively initializing the character data to `0`.

In the ASCII character set, the character code `0` corresponds to the NULL character, usually used for terminating strings in C.

Now, realize that it is a non-printable character and as such is represented with *two* characters in textual representation: `^@`.

`addch` and friends operate on a higher abstraction level than the mere fields you got in your terminal, they operate on characters, including non-printable characters.

From `man curs_addch`:

> If  `ch`  is  any  [non-whitespace] control  character, it is drawn in `^X`
>   notation.
>          Calling `winch` after adding a control  character  does  not  return  the
>          character  itself, but instead returns the `^`-representation of the control character.

Since ncurses sees that `COLOR_PAIR(RED)` contains the character code `0`, ncurses interprets it as a non-printable character and prints it accordingly, **one** character in **two** fields.

---